# How to start a LaunchAgent on login via ssh?

Tags: macos, ssh, launchd

I want to start an agent when I log in on my machine via ssh. I created the plist and set the key `LimitLoadToSessionType` to `StandardIO` according to the quite old [Technical Note on daemons and agents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION3), since it explicitly mentions ssh sessions. The plist is located under `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. In the plist I reference a very simple binary that does nothing other than sleeping for testing purposes. However, nothing happens when I log in via ssh. When I change `LimitLoadToSessionType` to `Aqua` the test app runs on logging into the gui as expected.

How can I start an agent when logging in via ssh?

Comment: It may be a permissions issue. Try doing `chmod 644 your.plist`. If that doesn't help, then try `chmod +x your.plist`.

Comment: By the way, there's a great app called [Launch Control](https://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/), which is only $18, that will help you install and troubleshoot your own launch agents.